# Getting -The XML page cannot be displayed - when running my Webservice locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

i have created a JSON webservice using asp.net  and i am connecting to it from my android application I wrote earlier ,

I am running the webservice locally using IIS ,
It is fully working  on my desktop , then i wanted to run it on my Laptop,
Did exactly what i did on my laptop however i can access only the main page (http://localhost:7489/Handler1.ashx)
when i try to move further it is giving me this error

> The XML page cannot be displayed  Cannot view XML input using style
>   sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or
>   try again later.
>
> ---
>
> Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource
>   'http://localhost:7489/Handler1.ashx?ANDROID'. Line 1,...
>
> {

What i have tried so far :

> aspnet_regiis.exe -i

To Re-register ASP.Net with IIS

and also made sure asp.net is checked in windows features

checked the application pool and setting it to ASP.NET V4.0

compared the (Application development features) in the  windows features with my Desktop(which the webservice is fully running on)
and what I have noticed is that I am missing those options on my laptob

.Net Extensibility 3.5-
.Net Extensibility 4.5-
ASP.NET 3.5-
ASP.NET 4.5

in mylaptob i can only see .Net Extensibility - ASP.NET

Any one can point me what is missing here ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please check the Content-Type header of the response? is it application/json?

Comment: @OguzOzgul Actually this webservice is using a json-rpc client library for android , so i am not able to see a (response ) from my browser, it works like if i enter this url in my browser
http://localhost:7489/Handler1.ashx?ANDROID

i should get a zip file which i will implement into my android project
Hope i was able to explain

Comment: Then it is just beyond my knowledge :( Sorry. But still. Since you can browse this from your browser, why not open developer tools and capture the network traffic? There you can see the headers as well as the response body.

Comment: @OguzOzgul i will be checking the network traffic as you suggested .. thanks :)